# Acces as3 function in swf embeded in html

Tags: javascript, html, embed, flash

Good morning to you all. This is code where I try to embed swf in html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./flash/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "ime_js";
            swfobject.embedSWF("flash/IMEJS.swf", "ime_js", "100", "100", "9.0.0", "flash/playerProductInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ime_js">
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to access function in that swf object.

```
swfobject.getObjectById("ime_js").init();
```

And then chrome console comes with this message:
TypeError: Object # has no method 'init'.

Swf object contains that function, it has been used already and it works. So swf is not an issue. Just part where I try to embed it and call its functions.
Please, do help :)

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: What is the value of swfobject.getObjectById("ime_js")?

ie, what does the console say when you write 'console.log(swfobject.getObjectById("ime_js"))'

Comment: @spassvogel Here it is:
<object type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash" id=​"ime_js" data=​"flash/​IMEJS.swf" width=​"100" height=​"100" style=​"visibility:​ visible;​">​</object>​